# Unable to find object even when it is defined and accessible in console Ionic2/3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to display the data gathered from a api implemented in .ts file on the html front in an Ionic3 Application.The code for my ts file is export

```
class PlaceDetailPage {
   public storeid = this.navParams.get('sid');
   public storeloc = this.navParams.get('sloc');
   public storedata : any ;
   public loader = this.loading.create({
       content: "Please wait..."
    });
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public globalProvider: GlobalProvider, public storage: Storage, public loading: LoadingController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public menuCtrl: MenuController){

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.loader.present()
    this.globalProvider.getstoreinfo(this.storeid,this.storeloc)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.storedata = data.storeDto;
            console.log("storefeed");
            console.log(this.storedata);
            this.loader.dismissAll();
        });
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PlaceDetailPage');
  }

  createPlan() {
    this.navCtrl.push(CreatePlanPage);
  }

}
```

But when I execute the above code and try to display it with html I get the following error

```
TypeError: _co.storedata is undefined
```

I have also console logged the result which is displayed after this error but my Html content fails to execute due to this error. unable to understand why the object seems unavailable to html but is then accessed by console.log.

Comment: Can you add the HTML please?

Answer (score 0):

In your class you declare type but not value. The below var (storedata) remains undefined until your lifecycle function (ionViewDidLoad) later assigns data to it.

public storedata : any ;

So to fix this:

one option is to assign some default placeholder data: storedata: any = “placeholder”;

another use ? in your template binding to indicate that the value may not exist and will be assigned later/asynchroniously

.

A note re your code: try to initialize your declared vars inside constructor method (within {}), this is more of convention.
You basically declare and ini those in place (thats not convention) - this may lead to issues for you...